# Wordpress Ultimate Member Profile pic Scaled Images

Tags: php, wordpress

We are using the Ultimate Member plugin and on our members directory page we have the profile images.

The default profile image is 190x190 and on upload saves a 80x80 version.

On the directory pages it is pulling in the 190x190 image rezising it to 80x80.

I want to be able to pull in the 80x80 image that exists. I have tried this in template files but the plugin has updated its code to out the profile pic

```
{{{user.avatar}}}
```

before I was able to set the `$avatar_size` to 80. Any ideas without changing UM's files to add a filter or hook to get it to fetch the 80x80 image?

Comment: What are your settings as per the [documentation](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1542-profile-photo-size)?

Comment: Lucan the documentation is limited.  It just says there is 3 sizes you can set for the profile images.  I have set 80x80 and 190x190 but still pulling in 80x80

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you want to profile image to display in 80x80 size?

Comment: Yes but its pulling in the 190x190 image and resizing to 80x80 BUT there is a 80x80 image which exists, so I need the code to pull that one in

Comment: Does `{user_avatar_small}` work?

Comment: Just as a note, for such a small image it would be better to keep the 190x190, as the 80x80 will appear blurry on Retina displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the one like the Garfield image in the second user card below, which is rendered via `templates/members.php` which by default uses the `members-grid.php` template (see the Ultimate Member's template structure [here](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1516-templates-map)):

[image: The Members page preview on Twenty Twenty]

Then if you don't already know, that section is using the WordPress script/JS templating, i.e. [`wp.template()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.template) (check `um_build_template()` in [`assets/js/um-members.js`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/ultimate-member/tags/2.1.6/assets/js/um-members.js#L355)) and that the Ultimate Member retrieves the (user and other) data using AJAX:

[image: Sample AJAX response]

And the class which handles the AJAX request is `Member_Directory` in [`includes/core/class-member-directory.php`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/ultimate-member/tags/2.1.6/includes/core/class-member-directory.php) which uses [`get_avatar()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/) and the (global) [Profile Photo Size setting](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1542-profile-photo-size).

So if you want to change the profile photo size there which defaults to the `190px x 190px` size:

### Easy way, without coding

Just change the Profile Photo Size setting (see *wp-admin » Ultimate Member → Settings → Appearance → Profile → Profile Photo Size*) to `80x80px`:

[image: Global Profile Photo Size setting]

### With coding, using a hook

In the `Member_Directory` class, there is one filter hook which you can use to easily change the profile photo URL so that it points to the `80px` size instead of the default `190px`.

So here's a working example to override the profile photo URL using the hook:

```php
// In your theme functions file.
add_filter( 'um_ajax_get_members_data', function ( $data_array, $user_id ) {
    $data_array['avatar'] = get_avatar( $user_id, 80 );
    /* Or use a custom data key:
    $data_array['avatar_80'] = get_avatar( $user_id, 80 );

    // Then in the template file, use:
    // {user.avatar_80 || user.avatar}
    */
    return $data_array;
}, 10, 2 );
```

### Additional Notes

As mentioned by [@Shoelaced](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1512787/shoelaced), "*the 80x80 will **appear blurry** on Retina displays*", so it might be better to just use the `190x190` and use CSS to scale it to `80x80`. For example:

```css
.um-directory .um-members-wrapper .um-members.um-members-grid .um-member.with-cover .um-member-photo a img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

And in fact, the default scaling (in [`assets/css/um-members.css`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/ultimate-member/tags/2.1.6/assets/css/um-members.css#L473)) is `90x90` (just `10px` greater than what you want..).

### So I hope this answer helps?

And I have tried and tested all the above code working as expected on WordPress 5.4.2 with Ultimate Member 2.1.6 (the latest release as of writing).